# Add PDT or PST in output display in mysql

Tags: mysql, timezone

How can i add the timezone display on my output? When its PDT, i wanted it to say PDT, and if its PST to automatically change to PST.

This is my current query

```
SELECT IF (DAYOFWEEK( CURDATE() ) = 1, DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(curdate(), INTERVAL 2 DAY), "%h:%i %p"), DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), "%h:%i %p"))
```

The output of this is

```
12:00 AM
```

It would be great if i can output the timezone and be like

```
12:00 AM PDT or 12:00 AM PST
```

Comment: mysql date/time values don't include TZ values. you'd have to TELL mysql what timezone to apply during string formatting.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL doesn't store the time zone, so the DATETIME value you have doesn't include a time zone. You have to store the time zone separately.

A little warning: If you store the timezone as "PST" or "PDT" it will be easy to display, but hard to convert to other time zones, as "PST" isn't unique, there are several different time zones with that abbreviation.

If you need to convert the DATETIME to other timezones, you should probably store the DATETIME as UTC, and store the time zone with it's full tz-name, like "America/New_York". However, then you probably need to use a programming language to handle all this, like Pyhton, Ruby, PHP, Java, as SQL generally doens't have very good time zone support, and AFAIK that's true for MySQL as well.